# Detecting history of keystrokes in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, graphics, xna, keyboard-events

So currently, I am a newb starting coding in c#. I started making a space game akin to space invaders and ran into an issue, in the draw method, I set it to draw my bullet and head upward on the string as soon as i hit space. But the problem was as soon as I let go of space, my bullet disappeared. I made a work around where as soon as the bullet left the screen it would teleport to the ship. Is there anyway to make the game check if the button has been pressed in the past and make the bullet keep moving until i want it to disappear.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

 namespace Spaceteroids
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    Texture2D spriteSheet;
    Texture2D laser;
    Texture2D Enemyship;
    spriteAnimation loading;
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    KeyboardState currentKeyboard;
    KeyboardState oldKeyboard;
    PlayerShip character;
    Rectangle characterRectangle;
    Bullet bullet;
    Bullet bullet2;
    bool heightCheck;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        currentKeyboard = new KeyboardState();
        oldKeyboard = new KeyboardState();
        //characterRectangle = new Rectangle((int)character.Position.X,(int)character.Position.Y, spriteSheet.Width / 4, spriteSheet.Height);
        character = new PlayerShip(new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - 40));
        bullet = new Bullet(new Vector2(character.Position.X, character.Position.Y - 20));

        base.Initialize();
    }
    void Movement()
    {
        if (IsHeld(Keys.A))
        {
            character.xSpeed = -6;
        }
        else if (IsHeld(Keys.D))
        {
            character.xSpeed = 6;
        }
        else
        {
            character.xSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    void Collision()
    {
        if (character.Position.X < 0)
        {
            character.Position.X = 0;
        }
        else if (character.Position.X + (spriteSheet.Width/4) > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width)
        {
            character.Position.X = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - (spriteSheet.Width/4) ;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        laser = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Laser");
        Enemyship = Content.Load<Texture2D>("EnemyShip");
        spriteSheet = Content.Load<Texture2D>("shipSpriteSheet");
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        loading = new spriteAnimation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("shipSpriteSheet"), 4);
        loading.Position = new Vector2(character.Position.X);
        loading.IsLooping = true;
        loading.FramesPerSecond = 30;
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        bullet.Position.X = character.Position.X;
        currentKeyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        oldKeyboard = currentKeyboard;
        loading.Update(gameTime, character);
        bullet.ySpeed = -10;

        bullet.UpdateBullet();

        Collision();
        Movement();
        if (NotPressed(Keys.Space))
        {
            bullet.Position.Y = character.Position.Y - 15;
        }
        if (bullet.Position.Y < 0)
        {
            bullet.Position.Y = character.Position.Y - 15;
        }

        character.UpdateShip();
        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();


      spriteBatch.Draw(laser, new Vector2(bullet.Position.X, bullet.Position.Y), Color.White);


        loading.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    public bool IsHeld(Keys key)
    {
        if (currentKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool IsReleased(Keys key)
    {
        if (currentKeyboard.IsKeyUp(key) && oldKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool JustPressed(Keys key)
    {
        if (currentKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key) && oldKeyboard.IsKeyUp(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool NotPressed(Keys key)
    {
        if (IsHeld(key) != true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool HasBeenPressed(Keys key)
    {
        if (oldKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

}
}
```

If you need any other information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing in XNA to track keystroke history (or anywhere else either). You have to do it yourself.

The usual solution to your problem is to maintain state on an object that represents the bullet. The keystroke may go away, but the object remains and keeps the bullet visible and moving until it is destroyed. You appear to have that state in your bullet object, so the likelihood is you just have logic errors in when to update it.

The problem is not instantly obvious from a quick read but your handling of keyboard state seems overly complex. All you need is key down and key up. All the rest you should track for yourself.

Comment: Do you know how I would do this? Like I said earlier, I'm very new to xna. Do you mean using enums?